# What happens in a try/catch/finally with no catch?

Tags: java, exception

Looking at a question I got wrong on a midterm test, this has me wondering:

```
public double[] readInputFile(String fielane) throws IOException
{
  File inputFile = new File(filename);
  Scanner in = new Scanner(inputFile);
  try
  {
    readData(in);
    return data;
  }
  finally
  {
    inputFile.close();
  }
}
```

Will this pass all exceptions back up the chain, or will it only pass the checked IOException?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `finally` block will be executed, and then originally-thrown exception (that is, the first exception that was thrown as a result of `readData(in)`) will percolate up.

I suppose that the caveat in this question is about the type of exception that will be percolated up. That could either be an `IOException`, or any sort of unchecked exception (that is, subclasses of `java.lang.RuntimeException` or `java.lang.Error`).

**EDITED** as per @zapl's comment: if the `finally` block throws an `IOException` (as a result of `inputFile.close()`), that exception will be percolated to the caller, regardless of whether the `try` block threw an exception or not.

Comment: So I guess that this method will "pass any type of exception back to the caller."? This is one of the optional multiple choice answers. Another (close) one is "This method will pass any IOException type errors back to the caller."

Comment: Any exception. That includes `IOException` (as stated in the `throws` clause), plus any instance of `RuntimeException` that might occur (`RuntimeException`s are unchecked exceptions. For example, `NullPointerException`). But the `finally` block will execute regardless.

Comment: The original `Exception` can be overridden if the `finally` block throws another `Exception` [> example](http://ideone.com/tzMCUG).

Answer (score 1):

The code within the `finally` block will always be executed, independent of whether or not an exception occurred within the `try` block above.

In your example, the `finally` block makes sure to close the input file; thus, it's guaranteed that the connection doesn't stay open, even when an exception is thrown.

Answer (score 1):

> Will this pass all exceptions back up the chain, or will it only pass the checked IOException?

It will pass up all the exceptions, but for the code to compile `readData` should be declared to throw only `IOException` or its sub-classes.

The `finally` block will be executed after the `try` block, just as usual.